# Number of tours through m x n grid?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

Let T(x,y) be the number of tours over a X × Y grid such that:

1. the tour starts in the top left square
2. the tour consists of moves that are up, down, left, or right one square,
3. the tour visits each square exactly once, and
4. the tour ends in the bottom left square.

It’s easy to see, for example, that T(2,2) = 1, T(3,3) = 2, T(4,3) = 0, and T(3,4) = 4.
Write a program to calculate T(10,4).

- I have been working on this for hours ... I need a program that takes the dimensions of the grid as input and returns the number of possible tours? Any idea on how I should go about solving this?

Comment: you have the right tags.. if you know how backtracking works this should be easy to implement. what's your problem?

Comment: and why T(2,2)=1? I can find two paths: 1 moving down 2 moving right-down-left. Maybe I misunderstood the problem...

Comment: @Manish: because there are 2 matching tours.. what number did you expect?

Comment: @Saphrosit: the tour visits each square exactly once

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Oh yes, sorry I skipped that rule :)

Comment: @ thb So you are saying i need to figure out a way to represent a tour inside the program and then try out different possiblities to see which one works?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Thanks for the hint ... I tagged back tracking because it came up often when I was trying to look for some similar problems. I dont actually know how it works? Can you give some hints?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath For a 3x3 grid, I expect a much larger number than 2! Perhaps I have misunderstood. There are at least 10 ways (and more) to get from top-left to bottom-left without visiting any square more than once. Why is T(4,3) 0?

Comment: @Manish Each square needs to be visited exactly once, so the path length needs to be X*Y.

Comment: According to my calculations, `T(10,4) = 2329`.

Comment: @davin do you mind giving some more details on how you solved it?

Comment: @user1277552, primitive backtracking, just like the answers explain. Once you've solved it yourself we can compare solutions.

Comment: @user1277552 just a little sidenote, but might help doing research: this problem is a variant of the hamiltonian path problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new to backtracking, this might give you an idea how you could solve this:

You need some data structure to represent the state of the cells on the grid (visited/not visited).

Your algorithm:

```
step(posx, posy, steps_left)
    if it is not a valid position, or already visited
        return
    if it's the last step and you are at the target cell
        you've found a solution, increment counter
        return
    mark cell as visited             
    for each possible direction:
       step(posx_next, posy_next, steps_left-1)
    mark cell as not visited
```

and run with

```
step(0, 0, sizex*sizey)
```

The basic building blocks of backtracking are: evaluation of the current state, marking, the recursive step and the unmarking.

This will work fine for small boards. The real fun starts with larger boards where you have to cut branches on the tree which aren't solvable (eg: there's an unreachable area of not visited cells).

Comment: @KarolyHarovath I dont understand what you use step+left for?

Comment: @KarolyHarovath Also how do I decide what posx_next and posy_next should  be and where do I add the code for that?

Comment: example: if you go to the right, posx_next = posx+1, posy_next = posy.

Comment: @KorolyHarvoth Can you tell me how I check which move from a specific  point in the grid is valid?

Comment: <code>#include <iostream>

int grid[3][3];
int c = 0;

int main(){    
    solve (0, 0, 9);
}

int solve (int posx, int posy, steps_left){
    if (grid[posx][posy] = 1){
        return 0;
    }
    if (steps_left = 1 && posx = 0 && posy = 2){
        c = c+1;
        return 0;
    }
    grid[posx][posy] = 1;
    // for all possible directions
    {
        solve (posx_next, posy_next, steps_left-1)
    }
    grid[posx][posy] = 0;
}
</code>

@KarolyHorvath it only deals with jsut one case right now. I cant seem to figure out how to check all directions ?

Comment: you're missing this part of the pseudocode `it is not a valid position`. and the are for directions, so for `step` calls.

Comment: @KarlyHorvath Yeah I need to figure out a way to make sure th program does not go out side the array.

But I dont quite understand what you are saying regading step?

Comment: I wrote some preliminary code ... .can you please check whether it is returning the correct solution! THanks!
http://codepad.org/uBRl1FGw

Comment: why do you ask me?? I see this in your question: `T(3,3) = 2`. `grid[posx][posy]` currently this get's executed even if the position is out of bounds.

Comment: I wrote the code exactly like the algorithm above (or I think I did). But it still does not give the correct results? http://codepad.org/ioLZ2EYl

Comment: Can I arrive at a more faster solution for a 4Xn board where n can be order of 10^6 or so?

Answer (score 0):

The assigned exercise is a good one.  It forces you to think through several concepts, step-by-step.  I cannot think all the concepts through for you, but maybe I can help by asking the following question.

At some point, your program must represent a *partially completed tour.*  That is, it must represent a path which does not yet pass through all the squares and has not yet reached its target in the bottom left, but which might do both if the path were later extended.  How do you mean to represent a *partially completed tour?*

If you can answer the question, and if you grasp the concept of recursion, then one suspects that you can solve the problem with some work but without too much real trouble.  To represent the *partially completed tour* is your obstacle, so my recommendation is that you go to work on that.

*Update:*  See the comment of @KarolyHorvath below.  If you have not yet learned the use of dynamically allocated memory (or, equivalently, of STL containers like std::vector and std::list), then you should rather follow his hint, which is a good hint in any case.

Comment: hint: there's no need to represent the *tour*

Comment: @KarolyHorvath:  You're right, of course, though the algorithm is more flexible if one does explicitly represent it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath are you saying this is not how we should do it? DO you have any ideas?

Comment: I wouldn't do represent the tour. sure, it's quite simple. but since this looks like a homework assignment I won't post a full answer... see my question in the comment section and please don't post here as it is not related to @thb's answer. thx.

Comment: The approach of @KarolyHorvath will enjoy far better performance for large grids.

Comment: @thb I dont quite understand how his approach will work? Can you help me out a bit?